# Decode URL on Mobile from '%7C' to '|'

Tags: javascript, wordpress, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

We are using the code below to be able to link to a specific tab on our website.

As it is currently made, it allows us to link to the specific tab by adding #member-tabs|3 to the URL, where member-tabs is the class, 3 is the tab to open, and they are separated by a "|".

**The Problem**: The symbol "|" is being encoded as "%7C", but is failing to be decoded on phone/tablet. I tried adding `replace('%7C', '|')`, but it didn't solve the issue.

Example: https://test.radacutlery.com/fundraising/tabs/#member-tabs|3

```
<script>

    function _setTab(){
        // get current hash value
        var curHash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        // only continue if hash provided and scoped to member tabs
         if( !curHash || !curHash.match('member-tabs') ){ return false; }
        // split and int val tab num
        curHash = parseInt(curHash.replace('%7C', '|')split('|')[1]);

        // testing the decodeURI
        decodeURI(curHash)

        // ignore if tab is current state
        if( curHash === window._tabSelected ){ return false; }
        // set current tab to window
        window._tabSelected = curHash;

        // add click event to tab selected
        switch(curHash){
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                jQuery('#member-tabs .et_pb_tab_'+curHash+' a').click();
            break;

            default:
                return false;
            break;
        }

        // scroll to tabs container
        _scrollToTabs();
    }

    // scroll to member tabs container with 50px offset
    function _scrollToTabs(){
        var oTabs = jQuery('#member-tabs');
        if( oTabs.length > 0 ){
            jQuery('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: (oTabs.offset().top - 50)
            }, 1000);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // set falsey state for tab selected on load
    window._tabSelected = false;

    // attach to window load because the tabs are initialized later in document
    jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
        // check for initial hash state
        _setTab();

        // add hash change window listener
        jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function(){
            _setTab()
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the issue, but I see a syntax bug on this line:

```
// split and int val tab num
curHash = parseInt(curHash.replace('%7C', '|')split('|')[1]);
```

Should have a period before `split` like so:

```
// split and int val tab num
curHash = parseInt(curHash.replace('%7C', '|').split('|')[1]);
```

Comment: That did solve it - thank you so much for noticing that bug!

Comment: Instead of doing a one off replacement though, you'll have much more resilient code if you use the javascript function that's built to transform encoded strings: [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function you want is [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```js
let encodedString ="1%7C2%7C3"
let decodedString = decodeURIComponent(encodedString)  // "1|2|3"
let parts = decodedString.split("|") // ["1","2","3"]
let numbers = parts.map(part => parseInt(part)) // [1,2,3]

console.log({decodedString, parts, numbers})
```